# Escaping characters when running Javascript in Applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

When using the `do shell script` command in AppleScript, it is often necessary to escape certain characters.  `Quoted form of` can be used for that purpose.

Is there an equivalent designed for Applescript's `do JavaScript` command?

Here's an example:

```
set message to "I'm here to collect $100"
do shell script "echo " & message
--> error
```

As written, the shell script returns an error because the apostrophe `'` and `$` are not treated as text by the shell.  The easiest and most generalizable solution is to take advantage of AppleScript's `quoted form of` which in one fell swoop escapes all offending characters in the `message` variable:

```
set message to "I'm here to collect $100"
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of message
--> "I'm here to collect $100"
```

Escaping individual occurrences of the offending characters is not a solution when the `message` variable changes repeatedly or is input by a lay user, etc.

The analogous situation can arise with `do JavaScript:

```
set theText to "I'm not recognized by Javascript because I have both
                an internal apostophe and line feed"

tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('IDgoesHere').value ='" & theText & "';" in document 1
```

Obviously the content of `theText` won't get "JavaScripted" into the intended text field because of the `'` and the `linefeed`.

Question: Does AppleScript have an equivalent to `quoted form of` that is designed to "escape" text that is specifically problematic for JavaScript.

Comment: `quoted form of` is not restricted to `do shell script`. You can use it everywhere however it follows the rules to optimize quotation in a shell environment.

Comment: @vadian Good to know! Thanks…..Still begs the question as to whether a similar feature is available specifically for Javascript.

Comment: specifically for Javascript there is none

Comment: If you'd post a code example, we could discuss more.

Comment: @ jweaks  As requested, I posted an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applescript isn't very good with text manipulation, but you can use it to escape the characters yourself.

You can use this subroutine from [Macosxautomation.com](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html):

```
on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
 set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
 set the item_list to every text item of this_text
 set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
 set this_text to the item_list as string
 set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
 return this_text
end replace_chars
```

Example:

```
set the message_text to "I'm an apostrophe"
set the message_text to replace_chars(message_text, "'", "&#39;")
```